# First column of sqlite table throwing error: no such column

Tags: sqlite

This seems odd to me and violates my previous experience with SQLite.  I have a trivial database with one table and 3 columns.  When I query the first column I get 'Error: no such column: Name'.  The other columns work fine.  Log below.  There must be something ridiculously basic that I am missing.  My sleazy work-around is to add a dummy first column, at which point querying on 'Name' works fine, but that is pretty unsatisfactory.  Running on a Mac mini (M1, 2020), macOS Monterey Version 12.5.1.

```
bash-3.2$ head Names/nameTest1.csv
﻿Name,Gender,Count
James,M,5304407
John,M,5260831
Robert,M,4970386
...

bash-3.2$ sqlite3 test1.db
SQLite version 3.19.3 2017-06-08 14:26:16
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .separator ','
sqlite> .import Names/nameTest1.csv testtable1
sqlite> .schema
.schema
CREATE TABLE testtable1(
  "﻿Name" TEXT,
  "Gender" TEXT,
  "Count" TEXT
);
sqlite> select * from testtable1 where Count='5304407';
James,M,5304407
sqlite> select * from testtable1 where Name='James';
Error: no such column: Name
sqlite> .quit
.quit
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file has the [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) field. It does not correspond to a printable character, so you do not see it, but SQLite fails to strip it and includes it as the the prefix of your *Name* field. This is a known issue, but recent versions of SQLite should handle it [properly](https://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_20_0.html). You might be using an older version. Either upgrade your SQLite or strip the BOM code before importing.